# MySqlException was unhandled during UPDATE

Tags: c#, mysql

Please help me, when i making a update e get error !

```
bdDataSet = new DataSet();
//Define string de conexão
bdConn = new MySqlConnection("Server=xxxxxxxxx;Database=xxxxxxx;Uid=xxxxxxx;Pwd=xxxxxxxx");
var command = bdConn.CreateCommand();
//Abre conecção
try
{
    bdConn.Open();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Impossível estabelecer conexão");
}
//Verifica se a conexão está aberta
if (bdConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    //ENCONTRA USUARIO  
    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=@email and senha=@senha";
    command.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxUser.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@senha", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPass.Text;
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        string email = reader.GetString("email");
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(reader["hd_id"]))
        {
            //ADD HD ID NO D


            MySqlCommand sql2 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE users SET hd_id=@hdid WHERE email=@email", bdConn);
            sql2.Parameters.Add("@hdid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = HardDrive.GetHDDSerialNo();
            sql2.Parameters.Add("@email", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
            sql2.ExecuteReader();
        }
        if (reader.GetString("hd_id") != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tem HD");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Usuários e/ou Senha Invalido");
    }

    bdConn.Close();
}
```

so I have error in this line

```
sql2.ExecuteReader();
```

Please helpe do solve this problem !! sorry for my english i'm from brazil. I've tried everything to do this query but I can not at all hope that any of you can help me!

Comment: Any time you “get error” you have to tell us what the error is.

Comment: what is error??

Answer (score 1):

Here in the case of your second query you need to use `sql2.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead for `sql2.ExecuteReader();`.

> The [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) perform catalog operations (for example,
> querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such
> as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a
> DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements. And the method will return the number of rows affected.

Whereas [ExecuteReader()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an object that can iterate over the entire result set.

A syou mentioned in the comment that error is not because of the ExecuteNonQuery, it is because of the previous Datareader, so you have to close them before processing the update.

Comment: It would be a much better answer if you explained why the poster should do this, so it provides information rather than just a copy/paste solution. It would help the poster avoid this same error in the future.

Comment: I already tried but it also does not work! see in this picture : http://prntscr.com/eszl0g

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do: close your previous connection, which was through a `DataReader`.

Comment: What code works to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Datareader. Datareader will keep the connection open till it is closed. If you use a connection for Data Reader then you cannot use it for Execute Non query.

Better you create a new connection and command object for update.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

Comment: How can i do this ? can you help me ?, I need the values returned in row.